Can independence in one coordinate system help us to determine random variable transformation in other coordinate system?
This question is linked with this question.
Let us take a complex random variable (not Gaussian) given by $z=x+jy$, its polar form is given by two other random variables $A\exp(j\Theta)$
Suppose I know marginal PDFs of $A$ and $\Theta$ where $A=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\Theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$. Furthermore I know both of $A$ and $\Theta$ to be independent of one another. I can then easily do the random variable transformation $x=A \cos\Theta$ and $y=A\sin\Theta$ to find the PDF of $x$ and $y$. Furthermore, the dependency structure between $x$ and $y$ can be easily found using Jacobian.
However, suppose I again know that $A$ and $\Theta$ are independent, but I do not know the marginal distributions of $A$ and $\Theta$. However, I know the marginal distributions of $x$ and $y$, Can I then find the distribution of $A$ and $\Theta$ if the dependency structure between random variables $x$ and $y$ is not known to me, i.e., $f_\text{xy}(x,y)$ is unknown.
If this is not possible then, does changing from one coordinate system to another involves loss of information in random variable transformation?

Your main question is: if you know the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, and you know that $A$ and $\Theta$ are independent, is that enough to fix the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ (or equivalently, the joint distribution of $(A,\Theta)$)?
The answer is no. Consider two cases:
(1) Uniform distribution on the disc $D:=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ (that is, $f_{XY}(x,y)=1/\pi$ for all $(x,y)\in D$, and $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$ otherwise).
(2) Uniform distribution on the intersection of the disc with the negative and positive quadrants,
$\widetilde{D}:=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1, \text{ and }xy\geq 0\}$ (given by $f_{XY}(x,y)=2/\pi$ for all $(x,y)\in \widetilde{D}$, and $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$ otherwise).
The distributions of $X$ and of $Y$ are the same in both cases, and $A$ and $\Theta$ are independent in both cases, but the joint distribution is not the same (and indeed the distribution of $\Theta$ is different). In case (1), $\Theta$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi)$, but in case (2), $\Theta$ is uniform on $[0,\pi/2)\cup[\pi,3\pi/2)$.
As to your final question: does changing from one coordinate system to another involve loss of information in random variable transformation? Basically, no. If you have $(X,Y)=g((U,V))$ for some bijective and "sufficiently nice" function $g$, then any event written in terms of $(X,Y)$, say $\{(X,Y)\in C\}$, can be rewritten as an event in terms of $(U,V)$, namely $\{(U,V)\in g^{-1}(C)\}$. Here "sufficiently nice" really means "measurable", and to define that rigorously one needs some measure theory. In your case, the statement "$A$ and $\Theta$ are independent" can be restated as "$\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\tan^{-1}(Y/X)$ are independent".
(Sometimes there is some annoying fiddling needed to write things nicely - for example here, what is the value of $\Theta$ corresponding to $X=Y=0$?)
